# Siddhi Send Performance Issues - Embedded

Tags: wso2, siddhi

We are evaluating Siddhi as a embedded CEP processor for our application. While scale testing we found that as you increase the number of rules the time it takes to insert an event increases significantly for each unique ID. For example:

- Create 10 rules (using windows and a partition by id)
- Load 1000 unique entries at a time. Track the timing. Note that insert performance increases from ms -> many seconds as you approach 100K unique entries. The more rules you have also increases this time.
- Now load the "next" time for each record - insertion time remains constant regardless of ID.

Here is a code file which reproduces this:

```
public class ScaleSiddhiTest {

    private SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

    @Test
    public void testWindow() throws InterruptedException {

        String plan = "@Plan:name('MetricPlan') \n" +
                "define stream metricStream (id string, timestamp long, metric1 double,metric2 double); \n" +
                "partition with (id of metricStream) begin \n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule0' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule1' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule2' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule3' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule4' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule5' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule6' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule7' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule8' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule9' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule10' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule11' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule12' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule13' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule14' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule15' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule16' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule17' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule18' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) \n" +
                "select id, avg(metric2) as value, 'Metric2-rule19' as ruleName\n" +
                "having value>-1.000000 \n" +
                "insert into outputStream;\n" +
                "end ;";


        // Generating runtime
        ExecutionPlanRuntime executionPlanRuntime = siddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(plan);

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        // Adding callback to retrieve output events from query
        executionPlanRuntime.addCallback("outputStream", new StreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void receive(Event[] events) {
                counter.addAndGet(events.length);
            }
        });

        // Starting event processing
        executionPlanRuntime.start();

        // Retrieving InputHandler to push events into Siddhi
        InputHandler inputHandler = executionPlanRuntime.getInputHandler("metricStream");

        int numOfUniqueItems = 10000;

        IntStream.range(0, 2).forEach(curMinute->{
            long iterationStartTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();
            AtomicLong lastStart = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
            IntStream.range(0, numOfUniqueItems).forEach(id->{
                try {
                    inputHandler.send(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(curMinute), new Object[]{id, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(curMinute), 10.0, 20.0});
                    if( id > 0 && id % 1000 == 0 ){
                        long ls = lastStart.get();
                        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        lastStart.set(curTime);
                        System.out.println("It took " + (curTime - ls) + " ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: " + counter.get());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e ){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("It took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - iterationStartTime) + "ms to load the last " + numOfUniqueItems);
        });

        // Shutting down the runtime
        executionPlanRuntime.shutdown();

        siddhiManager.shutdown();
    }

}
```

here are my questions:

1. Are we doing anything incorrect here that may be leading to the initial load performance issues?
2. Any recommendations to work around this problem?

UPDATE:
Per an suggested answer below I updated the test to use group by instead of partitions. The same growth is shown for initial load of each object, except it is even worse:
 Specifically, I changed the rules to:

```
@Plan:name('MetricPlan') 
define stream metricStream (id string, timestamp long, metric1 double,metric2 double); 

from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000) 
select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule0' as ruleName
group by id 
having value>-1.000000 
insert into outputStream;

...
```

Here are the result outputs for the Group By vs Partition By. Both show the growth for the initial load.

**Group By Load Results**

```
Load 10K Items - Group By        
It took 3098 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 20020        
It took 2507 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 40020        
It took 5993 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 60020        
It took 4878 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 80020        
It took 6079 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 100020        
It took 8466 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 120020        
It took 11840 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 140020        
It took 12634 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 160020        
It took 14779 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 180020        
It took 87053ms to load the last 10000        

Load Same 10K Items - Group By        
It took 31 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 220020        
It took 22 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 240020        
It took 19 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 260020        
It took 19 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 280020        
It took 17 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 300020        
It took 20 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 320020        
It took 17 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 340020        
It took 18 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 360020        
It took 18 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 380020        
It took 202ms to load the last 10000
```

**Partition By Load Results**

```
Load 10K Items - Partition By        
It took 1148 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 20020        
It took 1870 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 40020        
It took 1393 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 60020        
It took 1745 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 80020        
It took 2040 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 100020        
It took 2108 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 120020        
It took 3068 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 140020        
It took 2798 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 160020        
It took 3532 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 180020        
It took 23363ms to load the last 10000        

Load Same 10K Items - Partition By        
It took 39 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 220020        
It took 21 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 240020        
It took 30 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 260020        
It took 22 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 280020        
It took 35 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 300020        
It took 26 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 320020        
It took 25 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 340020        
It took 34 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 360020        
It took 48 ms to load the last 1000 entities. Num Alarms So Far: 380020        
It took 343ms to load the last 10000
```

This type of growth almost seems to imply that on load of an ID which is not found it is compared against every other ID, instead of leveraging a hash etc. Hence the linear growth we see as the number of unique IDs increase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior is as expected. 
When you use a partition with ID for each new ID you push a new instance of the partition is created, so if your partition is big it may have taken more time to create the partition. In the second time since the partition is already created for the unique ID it processes that faster.

In your case, I don't think using a partition is an ideal solution. Partition is only useful if you have inner streams or when you use non time based windows.

E.g.

`partition with (id of metricStream) 
begin 
   from metricStream ...
   insert into #TempStream ;
   from #TempStream ....
   select ... 
   insert into outputStream;
end;`

If you want to just group time-based aggregations then use the `group by` keyword.

`from metricStream#window.externalTime(timestamp, 300000)
 select id, avg(metric1) as value, 'Metric1-rule18' as ruleName
 group by id
 having value>-1.000000
 insert into outputStream;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my question with results of using group by vs partition by. Results are the same, though even worse for initial load. It seems to imply that we traverse all nodes when a new key is found